# Flexbox height based on content and min-height

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a column of 3 divs and I'd like one column's height to be adjusted to it's content.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9w488bo7/1/

```
<div class="column">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block block2">
    <br /> A
    <br /> A
    <br /> A
  </div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>

<style>
  .column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 500px;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .block {
    min-height: 50px;
    background: blue;
    flex: 1;
  }

  .block2 {
    background: red;
  }

</style>
```

Here is what I want:

[image]

And what I have:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `flex: 1` from `.block2` element so it doesn't grow in height.

```css
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 500px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.block:not(.block2) {
  min-height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  flex: 1;
}

.block2 {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block block2">
    <br /> A
    <br /> A
    <br /> A
  </div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was so close... Thanks a lot! :)